# Change Directory "cd" fails in Tamir.ssh

Tags: c#, ssh

Having trouble understanding why "cd .." does not execute in Tamir.ssh.
All other commands that I need to run work fine..
Has anyone else come across the same issue, and if so what was the fix please?

Relevant bits below

```
SshExec exec = new SshExec("192.168.0.1", "admin", "haha"); 
exec.Connect();
string stdOut = null;
string stdError = null;
exec.RunCommand("cd ..", ref stdOut, ref stdError);
```

Comment: Why do you think the cd command isn't executing? Do you get an error? What is the error?

Comment: because when I have also done a "pwd" command before and after the "cd .." the path is still the same.. Also get "file does not exist" when I expect to have navigated to correct directory..

Answer (score 0):

```
exec.RunCommand("cd ..", ref stdOut, ref stdError);
```

Each call to `RunCommand()` will create a separate channel which runs independently of the others. In the common case (making an ssh connection to a unix server), each channel will invoke a separate shell instance. A command like `cd` run in one channel won't affect subsequent commands launched in different channels.

To do what you want, you have to arrange to run the sequence of commands in the same `RunCommand` invocation. Assuming the remote server is a unix server invoking a shell like `bash`, you can use shell syntax, for example:

```
sshExec.RunCommand("pwd && cd .. && pwd", ref out, ref err);
```